# Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 4

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm new to Django, and trying to pass api results (dictionaries within a list) to a template using context.

I have tried doing this

```
{% if apiList != "Error..." %}
    {% for i in apiList %}
      {% for key, value in i %}
        {{ key }} {{ value }}<br>
      {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endif %}
```

but I get the error

```
Need 2 values to unpack in for loop; got 4.
```

When I do the same code but take out the value, so it just searches for the keys, it works fine and prints out all the keys on a new line. I've also tried the following code:

```
{% for key, value in apiList.items %}
   {{ key }} : {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

but this does not seem to work either, it does not give an error, but nothing shows on the screen.

Any idea how to solve this problem? Here is my code in the views.py

```
try:
            apiList = json.loads(api_request.content)

        except Exception as e:
            apiList = "Error..."
        return render(request, 'financials.html', {'apiList': apiList})
    else:
        return render(request, 'financials.html', {})
```

Thanks!

EDIT: Here is an example of the data in apiList:

```
[
{
date: "2020-09-26",
symbol: "AAPL",
fillingDate: "2020-10-30",
acceptedDate: "2020-10-29 18:06:25",
period: "FY",
revenue: 274515000000,
costOfRevenue: 169559000000,
grossProfit: 104956000000,
grossProfitRatio: 0.382332477278109,
researchAndDevelopmentExpenses: 18752000000,
generalAndAdministrativeExpenses: 19916000000,
sellingAndMarketingExpenses: 0,
otherExpenses: 803000000,
operatingExpenses: 38668000000,
costAndExpenses: 208227000000,
interestExpense: 0,
depreciationAndAmortization: 11056000000,
ebitda: 77344000000,
ebitdaratio: 0.281747809773601,
operatingIncome: 66288000000,
operatingIncomeRatio: 0.241473143544069,
totalOtherIncomeExpensesNet: 803000000,
incomeBeforeTax: 67091000000,
incomeBeforeTaxRatio: 0.244398302460703,
incomeTaxExpense: 9680000000,
netIncome: 57411000000,
netIncomeRatio: 0.209136112780722,
eps: 3.31,
epsdiluted: 3.28,
weightedAverageShsOut: 17352119000,
weightedAverageShsOutDil: 17528214000,
link: "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/0000320193-20-000096-index.htm",
finalLink: "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/320193/000032019320000096/aapl-20200926.htm"
},
```

Comment: Sounds like that happens here; `{% for key, value in i %}` so it really depends what is in `apiList`. Just debug it by outputting the extra values; `{% for key, value, x, y in i %}`

Comment: please share a sample data content for apiList, the queryset data from backend

Comment: I tried to output the extra values, and oddly enough it changed to "Need 4 values to unpack in for loop; got 6.

Comment: I've also added an example from the data!

Answer (score 0):

try this (i think this can help you to loop through key, value )

```
{% for key, value in apiList.iteritems() %}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. It says "Could not parse the remainder: '()'

Comment: sorry you should remove parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
{% for key, value in apiList.items %}
```